# Identification of the soundtrack that plays just before the ending of Naruto Episode 5?

Tags: naruto, music

What is the name of the soundtrack that plays just before the end of episode 5 of Naruto: 'You Failed! Kakashi's Final Decision'?

**It plays after the guitar solo and right before the ending credits play.** It starts when Naruto, Sakura, and Sasuke realize they have just passed their teamwork test to become Ninjas. Naruto was tied to a tree trunk, Sakura and Sasuke were eating and decided to share their lunch with Naruto.

Comment: Could it be this one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TsE01qdy5A i watched the episode years ago, but this ost has an little guitar solo. Maybe the used it or a vartion on it

Comment: It wasn't that one.  But I did use that link to find the song on YouTube.  So thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The songs name is "Victory" from Naruto OST 1.  https://youtu.be/Ls0IE8uPp4g

Answer (score -1):

It's [Wind](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_(ending)) performed by Akeboshi.

It was the first ending song in the Japanese version of Part I of the Naruto series. It was replaced by Harmonia in Episode 26.

Comment: No, not the ending credits. Right before the ending credits there's a guitar solo that plays. It happens when Sakura and Sasuke decide to give Naruto their lunch while he is tied up to a tree trunk.

Comment: Down voted, because there was specifically asked for a song with guitar solo. And Wind doesn't have any.

Comment: I found it. It's called "Victory". I had no idea that there were dozens of songs from the show that could be found on YouTube. Some of which are as amazing as "Victory". Thanks for the help guys.